# android SQLite help select last 10

Tags: android, sqlite, select

hello i use this code for diplay my conversation list

```
private Cursor getMessages( SQLiteDatabase db, boolean justNewMessages) {


    final String table = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION;
                                                                            //index
    final String[] columns = { Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_ID,       //0
                               Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE,     //1
                               Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM,     //2
                               Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_TO,       //3
                               Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_MSG       //4
        };

    String selection;

    if(justNewMessages) {
        selection = "(" + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM + " = '" + jid +"' or "
                        + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_TO + " = '" + jid + "') and "
                        + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_NEW + " = '1'";
    } else {
        selection = "(" + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM + " = '" + jid +"' or "
                        + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_TO + " = '" + jid + "')";
    }

    final String[] selectionArgs = null;
    final String groupBy = null;
    final String having = null;
    final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE;

    return db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy);
}
```

I would like select 10 last i try

```
final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE + " DESC LIMIT 10";
```

it is the last conversation, but reversed(the last word is up) how Select only 10 last conversation
OR delete and leaves the 10 last conversation and display this ... Cant you help me to start idea I do not understand ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FIXED Thanks for the tips it's the solution, thanks thanks thanks

Fixed by

```
final String tableff ="Select "+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_ID+","+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE+","+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM+","+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_TO+","+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_MSG+" from ["+table+"] WHERE "+selection+" LIMIT ((Select count(["+Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE+"]) from ["+table+"] WHERE "+selection+")-10),10";

    return db.rawQuery(tableff, selectionArgs);
```

Answer (score 2):

try out this query,

```
Select * from [table] LIMIT 
((Select count([any_column_name]) from [table])-10),10
```

this will fetch last 10 rows of your table.
replace *any_column_name* with any Column of yr table.

Regards,
Nital Shah

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE + " DESC";
final String limit= 10;

return db.query(table, columns, selection, selectionArgs, groupBy, having, orderBy, limit);
```

Comment: it's same of "final String orderBy = Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_DATE + " DESC LIMIT 10";"
this is last conversation but reversed the last word is up to list

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you're saying, could you explain what error you're getting?

Comment: the select is wrong my list is reversed normally is 10:00 word1<br>10:01 word2, with this i word2 in up and word1 in down, voila :)  
But is well the 10 last conversation...

Comment: Sorry but I'm not quite able to follow you, maybe you could include in your answer some input values for the query and expected output.

Comment: or how delete and keep only the last ten element 

i this, but delete all
db.delete(Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION,
    Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_FROM + " = '" + jid + "' or "
    + Constants.TABLE_CONVERSATION_FIELD_TO + " = '" + jid + "'",
    null);